# Vlookup or table join from a cell with a comma separated list

Tags: r, excel, vlookup

I have a .csv table that looks like this:

```
+----+------------------+
| ID |       CODE       |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | W002, W103, W111 |
|  2 | W002, W104       |
|  3 | W103, W111, W202 |
|  4 | W202, W103       |
+----+------------------+
```

I have a separate description data for what each of the "WXXX" codes mean. That looks like this:

```
+------+--------+
|  ID  |  CODE  |
+------+--------+
| W002 | Blue   |
| W103 | Red    |
| W111 | Green  |
| W202 | Orange |
+------+--------+
```

I want to create a data set that merges the to together and looks like this:

```
+----+--------------------+
| ID |        Code        |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | Blue, Red, Green   |
|  2 | Blue, Red          |
|  3 | Red, Green, Orange |
|  4 | Orange, Red        |
+----+--------------------+
```

I tried running a vlookup in excel, but it wouldn't recognize each Wxxx code. I would prefer running this all in R however, but understand that a left join wouldn't work either.

```
data_codes = read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE)
data_colors = read.csv("colors.csv", header = TRUE)
data_join= merge(x = data_codes, y = data_colors, by = "ID", all.x = TRUE
```

Actual results do not show each of the Wxxx codes separated by the comma

Comment: This can be done with Office 365 or later using TEXTJOIN.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to give you a general idea. You can use `separate_rows`, followed by `inner(left)_join`, `group_by` and `summarize`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a <- data.frame(id = 1:4,
                code = c("W002, W103, W111",
                         "W002, W104",
                         "W103, W111, W202",
                         "W202, W103"), stringsAsFactors = F)

a2 <- data.frame(id = c("W002", "W103", "W111", "W202"),
                 code = c("Blue", "Red", "Green", "Orange"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
a <- a %>% separate_rows(code, sep = ', ')

a3 <- inner_join(a, a2, by = c('code' = 'id'))
a3 <- a3 %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(code = paste0(code.y, collapse = ', '))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. so to be clear, the dataset is all just regular .csv files, there are no "|" in the data. I just had to use that as a tool to show a table properly in stackoverflow.

Comment: @DeebaYavrom I understand this. I just used some extra reprocessing to convert your provided data to data frames. The logic is still the same, and the solution works.

Comment: @DeebaYavrom Edited my original post